# Laravel 9: Undefined type 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route'. Intelephense 1009

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, intelephense

Can anyone help me? I'm still a beginner in Laravel. So, this error appeared when I just did a git clone project. After that I opened the project with vsCode and immediately got lots of errors.

**Error :**

> Undefined type 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route'. intelephense(1009)

> Undefined function 'redirect'. intelephense(1010)

> Undefined type 'Auth'. intelephense(1009)

> Undefined function 'response'. intelephense(1010)

I am very grateful to those who can help me find how to fix this error. Thank You!

Comment: Does `ctrl + shift + p` -> `Index workspace` fix it?

Comment: Oh god, thank you it worked! Of the many ways that I tried, it didn't work, and I finally found a way. Once again, thank you Mr Wahyu! May God repay your kindness

Comment: Glad to help. I post it as answer

Answer (score 17):

`Ctrl + Shift + P` -> `Intelephense: Index workspace` to fix it

Comment: And if it doesn't work?